# Group By Sum & Sort several workbooks contained within a file

Tags: excel, vba, loops

**My Goal:** I have a file (F) that contains several workbooks, each workbook has the same format and are around 40k rows.

the form of each workbooks is as follows:

[image]

I want to get this final output within a master worbook which contains one sheet per looped workbook (contained in F).

I know that a pivot table does very well the job. But I want it automatic and I have many files within F ...

What would be your strategy, would you still use pivot table and do a sort of loop for each files? Would you use SQL, other idea ...?

Many thanks for your feedback and approach on that.

Comment: "I have a file (F) that contains several workbooks" do you really mean "several work*sheets*" ?

Comment: I would vote for Power Pivot, it's automatic. After you setup the dashboard you can refresh the table and it will automate populate for next year as more data will flow in etc..

Comment: Thank you for that, so,  by using  vba and by doing Loop for each workbook so we set the pivots?

Comment: Yes, one possible way to go or set up manually for one (first time always take a little bit longer) and then apply it to the rest. You can also link all the workbooks to one master workbook. The workbooks will then be external sources. The combinations are quite endless :)

Answer (score 1):

I would at least give it a try. This went really fast to create and gives you an idea of the ability of power pivot. You can see how I arrange the Rows and Columns to the right in the PivotTable Fields.

So Power Pivot!

[image]

Comment: Sure very powerful, lets get into pivot table with VBA then.. good luck to me. Thank you for this feed-back.